# Executing password-protected psql from python

Tags: python, psql

I need to execute the following command from Python on *Windows*:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f script.sql db_name
```

The above script works fine when ran from git bash / powershell. After entering the script in a terminal, I need to provide a password to confirm it (similar to when using `sudo`).

How can I do that? I keep finding solutions that I think are linux-based.

How do I do it on Windows? I have tried many variations of solutions involving `subprocess`, i.e:

```
import subprocess

p2 = subprocess.Popen(
    'psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f script.sql db_name',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True)

print('this will print')
sudo_prompt = p2.communicate('THE_PASSWORD' + '\n')[1]
print('this will not')
```

Comment: Just set the environment variable `PGPASSWORD` prior to the subprocess call

Comment: This seems not to work even if I do `set PGPASSWORD=THE_PASSWORD` prior to executing the psql _from the terminal itself_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option (more secure) than invoking `psql` with explicit mention of your password is to have a [`.pgpass` file as described in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/libpq-pgpass.html) file (and keep it protected e.g. `chmod 600 ~/.pgpass`). This keeps your password out of the list of running processes.

On Windows:

> On Microsoft Windows the file is named `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` (where `%APPDATA%` refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile).

Comment: it doesn't matter: the idea is the same, just the location is different (see the link to the doc)